# (How to) Outsource GWT-internationalization?

Tags: java, gwt, maven-3

My project team develops a browsergame with GWT with a Maven-structure:

- Parent

  - Api
  - Domain
  - Service
  - View

GWT is used mainly in the view (except for inheriting the other modules to the view) and we implemented the internationalization there. So far this configuration is running.

Now we wanted to also internationalize different error-messages which will be thrown to the user's view, but coming from the Service-module.
Therefore it would be advantegeously to access the same property-files as the View-module. The problem is (obviously) that we cannot access the view from the service because of its order in the parent pom.

Would it be possible to outsource the internationalization-interface into the api so that we can access it from everywhere?

Thanks in advance.

---

Specialization:

Wether it's not as easy as I might think or I did something wrong. I try to specialize my problem to check out the problem I have.

I have a Api.gwt.xml within the Api-module (de.ba.sy.api), referencing to my packages in there:

```
<module>
<!-- <inherits name="de.ba.sy.api.manager.IUserManager" /> -->
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.User" />


<!-- Hier können weitere packages eingefügt werden -->
<source path="dao" />
<source path="encoder" />
<source path="entity" />
<source path="exceptions" />
<source path="language" />
<source path="mail" />
<source path="manager" />
<source path="user" />
<source path="validator" />
</module>
```

The interface ILanguage and also the properties lie within the language-package.

- de.ba.sy.api.language

  - ILanguage.class
  - ILanguage_de.properties
  - ILanguage_en.properties
  - ILanguage.properties

Within the View-module there's lying the structure:

- de.ba.sy.view

  - Application.gwt.xml (inheriting the Api-module)
  - client

    - Application.class

In Application.class I have now the code:

```
package view.client;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.core.shared.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;

import de.ba.sy.api.language.ILanguage;

/**
 * @author stubbe
 * Entry point classes define <code>onModuleLoad()</code>.
 */
public class Application implements EntryPoint {

    /**
     * This is the entry point method.
     */
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        /* Internationalisierung */
        final ILanguage languages = GWT.create(ILanguage.class);

        LoginPageForm login = new LoginPageForm(languages);
        RootPanel.get().add(login);
    }
}
```

So like I said if I keep the ILanguage and its properties within the View-module there's no problem, but when I move it into the Api-module I get:

```
[INFO] --- gwt-maven-plugin:2.5.0-rc1:compile (default-cli) @ View ---
[INFO] auto discovered modules [view.Application]
[INFO] Compiling module view.Application
[INFO]    Validating units:
[INFO]       Ignored 5 units with compilation errors in first pass.
[INFO] Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to TRACE or DEBUG to see all errors.
[INFO]    Computing all possible rebind results for 'de.ba.sy.api.language.ILanguage'
[INFO]       Rebinding de.ba.sy.api.language.ILanguage
[INFO]          Invoking generator com.google.gwt.i18n.rebind.LocalizableGenerator
[INFO]             Processing interface de.ba.sy.api.language.ILanguage
[INFO]                Generating method body for email()
[INFO]                   [ERROR] No resource found for key 'email'
[INFO] com.google.gwt.i18n.rebind.AbstractResource$MissingResourceException: No resource found for key 'email'
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.i18n.rebind.MessagesMethodCreator.createMethodFor(MessagesMethodCreator.java:1086)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.i18n.rebind.AbstractLocalizableImplCreator.delegateToCreator(AbstractLocalizableImplCreator.java:501)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.i18n.rebind.MessagesImplCreator.emitMethodBody(MessagesImplCreator.java:92)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.user.rebind.AbstractGeneratorClassCreator.genMethod(AbstractGeneratorClassCreator.java:277)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.user.rebind.AbstractGeneratorClassCreator.emitMethods(AbstractGeneratorClassCreator.java:239)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.user.rebind.AbstractGeneratorClassCreator.emitClass(AbstractGeneratorClassCreator.java:118)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.i18n.rebind.AbstractLocalizableImplCreator.generateConstantOrMessageClass(AbstractLocalizableImplCreator.java:225)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.i18n.rebind.LocalizableGenerator.generate(LocalizableGenerator.java:151)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.i18n.rebind.LocalizableGenerator.generate(LocalizableGenerator.java:124)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.core.ext.IncrementalGenerator.generateNonIncrementally(IncrementalGenerator.java:40)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.StandardGeneratorContext.runGeneratorIncrementally(StandardGeneratorContext.java:657)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.RuleGenerateWith.realize(RuleGenerateWith.java:41)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle$Rebinder.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:79)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:276)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:265)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.DistillerRebindPermutationOracle.getAllPossibleRebindAnswers(DistillerRebindPermutationOracle.java:91)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.handleGwtCreate(UnifyAst.java:355)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.handleMagicMethodCall(UnifyAst.java:433)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.endVisit(UnifyAst.java:237)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodCall.traverse(JMethodCall.java:243)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:265)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:116)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JCastOperation.traverse(JCastOperation.java:65)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:265)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:116)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JCastOperation.traverse(JCastOperation.java:65)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:265)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:116)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JDeclarationStatement.traverse(JDeclarationStatement.java:48)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor$ListContextImmutable.traverse(JModVisitor.java:170)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.acceptWithInsertRemoveImmutable(JModVisitor.java:336)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JBlock.traverse(JBlock.java:83)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:137)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:133)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodBody.traverse(JMethodBody.java:82)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:265)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethod.visitChildren(JMethod.java:426)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethod.traverse(JMethod.java:395)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:265)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst.mainLoop(UnifyAst.java:902)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst.exec(UnifyAst.java:627)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:604)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaScriptCompiler.java:33)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:278)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:229)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:141)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:232)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:198)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:170)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:88)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:82)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:177)
[INFO]                   [WARN] Searched the following resources:
[INFO]    [ERROR] Errors in 'view/client/Application.java'
[INFO]       [ERROR] Line 23: Failed to resolve 'de.ba.sy.api.language.ILanguage' via deferred binding
[INFO]    [WARN] For the following type(s), generated source was never committed (did you forget to call commit()?)
[INFO]       [WARN] de.ba.sy.api.language.ILanguage_
```

Thank you again. I just started with GWT, therefore I don't know if this is trivial or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since GWT 2.5, you can use `GWT.create()` in a JVM (i.e. on the server), provided there's a registered provider for the class passed as argument; and it comes with internationalization built-in, so you can use your interface and `GWT.create()` call on the server.

To answer your question then: yes, you can move the interface and properties files to your Api module.

---

Note that you have to use the `com.google.gwt.core.shared.GWT` class, not `com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT`.

Comment: Are you sure the properties files are available to the GWT compiler/devmode? They should be in `src/main/resources` in the Api module, and end up in its `target/classes` and produced JAR artifact (to be usable server-side). If they are in `src/main/java`, then check that they are present in the `-sources.jar` for the Api module (though it depends how you're packaging it)

Comment: Works. Great! Thank you! :)
I had to include the property-resources in the Api.pom finally (forgot that). The properties lie within the package (src/main/java) now (didn't work as wished in the src/main/resources)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to create a custom enum for the different types of errors that can be thrown from the server. You could then set the error type inside the exceptions thrown from the server, using an instance variable of the enum type. Upon receiving the exception, the client would convert the enum values to the "real" error messages, most likely using a switch-case statement.

You could also do the same using multiple exception types instead of an enum, but I personally prefer to use enums.